# Pandas Resample with Linear Interpolation

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-resample

I have some hourly data, such as below, with odd sample times.

| # | Date Time, GMT-08:00 | Temp, °C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10/31/23 15:51 | 13.41 |
| 2 | 10/31/23 16:51 | 7.49 |
| 3 | 10/31/23 17:51 | 7.61 |
| 4 | 10/31/23 18:51 | 7.39 |
| 5 | 10/31/23 19:51 | 7.34 |
| 6 | 10/31/23 20:51 | 7.33 |
| 7 | 10/31/23 21:51 | 7.38 |

I would like to resample with interpolation so the data points occur on the hour. I.e. 1500, 1600, 1700...

I assumed the following would work, but I've been unable to make this do what I expected.

`df.resample('60min').first().interpolate('linear')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC:

- First use [`df.resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) to resample your series into 1 minute bins (`'T'`), get [`.first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.first.html), and apply linear interpolation ([`.interpolate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.interpolate.html)), `method='linear'` being the default.
- Next, downsample into hourly bins (`'H'`), and apply [`.asfreq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.asfreq.html).

```py
import pandas as pd

# df
data = {'Date Time, GMT-08:00': {1: '10/31/23 15:51', 2: '10/31/23 16:51', 
                                 3: '10/31/23 17:51', 4: '10/31/23 18:51', 
                                 5: '10/31/23 19:51', 6: '10/31/23 20:51', 
                                 7: '10/31/23 21:51'}, 
        'Temp, °C': {1: 13.41, 2: 7.49, 3: 7.61, 4: 7.39, 5: 7.34, 6: 7.33, 7: 7.38}
        }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# preliminary steps: convert to timestamps & set as index
df['Date Time, GMT-08:00'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date Time, GMT-08:00'], 
                                            format='%m/%d/%y %H:%M')

df = df.set_index('Date Time, GMT-08:00')

# resample to 1min, get first, interpolate, resample to 1h, and get `asfreq`
df = df.resample('T').first().interpolate().resample('H').asfreq()
df

                      Temp, °C
Date Time, GMT-08:00          
2023-10-31 15:00:00        NaN
2023-10-31 16:00:00    12.5220
2023-10-31 17:00:00     7.5080
2023-10-31 18:00:00     7.5770
2023-10-31 19:00:00     7.3825
2023-10-31 20:00:00     7.3385
2023-10-31 21:00:00     7.3375
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

# Example data
data = {
    'Date Time, GMT-08:00': [
        '10/31/23 15:51', '10/31/23 16:51', '10/31/23 17:51',
        '10/31/23 18:51', '10/31/23 19:51', '10/31/23 20:51',
        '10/31/23 21:51'
    ],
    'Temp, °C': [13.41, 7.49, 7.61, 7.39, 7.34, 7.33, 7.38]
}

# Convert to DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Convert the date-time column to datetime objects and set as index
df['Date Time, GMT-08:00'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date Time, GMT-08:00'], format='%m/%d/%y %H:%M')
df = df.set_index('Date Time, GMT-08:00')

# Resample to hourly intervals, using the mean to aggregate and interpolate missing values
resampled_df = df.resample('H').mean().interpolate('linear')

print(resampled_df)
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not right. The first value that can be interpolated is for 1600, which should be between 13.4 and 7.5. This essentially just resets all the timestamps and keeps all the temperature values as they were originally.